raycast node sample nearest surface but is hit mesh island only
I have three lines (with the attribute spline ID named "orig"). I then subdivide and split each line into three parts and scale down a bit all of them. I'm raycasting all these lines onto a surface composed of multiple mesh islands. To approximate the positions for points that do not hit the surface, I am using the "Sample Nearest Surface" node. I want the "Sample Nearest Surface" node to consider only the hit surface mesh island for each "orig ID."



Not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work.

